# AWS Educate Starter account getting launch failed on g2.2xlarge instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to launch a `g2.2xlarge` Ubuntu deep learning ami on aws student starter account but getting launch failed with authorization error.

I have limit of `5 g2.2xlarge instances`. 
I am able to launch t2 instances.
Images are attached  below .

Instance limit image
[image]

EC2 dashboard
[image]

AMI image
[image]

instance type
[image]

Launch Error image
[image]

Comment: attach images inline.

Comment: Try decoding the message: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/decode-authorization-message.html

Answer (score 0):

AWS Educate Starter accounts are limited in the instances that can be launched. They are managed by a third party. These are the supported instance types:

> Supported Instance Types: t2.small, t2.micro, t2.nano,
>   m4.large, c4.large, c5.large,m5.large, t2.medium,
>   m4.xlarge, c4.xlarge, c5.xlarge, t2.2xlarge, m5.2xlarge,
>   t2.large, t2.xlarge, m5.xlarge

See here for more information: [Differences between AWS Educate Starter account and AWS account](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/educate-starter-account/)